# Is it known whether $6\times 10^n\pm 1$ is a twin prime for some $n>2$?

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, twin-primes

I checked the number pairs $6 \times 10^n \pm 1$ for $1 \le n \le 2000$.

The only twin primes of the desired form I found are: $(59, 61)$ and $(599, 601)$.

I wonder if these are the only pairs.

> What is the smallest twin prime of the form $6 \times 10^n \pm 1$ with $n > 2$ ?

Comment: Certain numbers with a form resembling yours are doomed to be composite, so an asymptotic probabilistic argument doesn't necessarily say anything about whether there are more twin primes of your form. I'm curious how you determined that one element of your pair was composite for such large $n$. Did you find a small factor, or use probabilistic primality testing?

Comment: Of course, I used the Rabin-Miller test.

Comment: I meant no offense about your heuristic argument, I hope you didn't take it that way. About expectation of OP's, from what I've seen as long as you've done some work (e.g. checking up to $n = 2000$), you don't have to worry and even more than that, if your question is interesting and you have enough reputation (which seems to be the case for you) then people will often just assume that you have put in some effort and not demand to see it.

Comment: It is an interesting question, although I must say that it took my breath away a bit to see the phrase "there should be infinitely many such twin primes"! :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OEIS has sequences [A056716](http://oeis.org/A056716) (-1) and [A056805](http://oeis.org/A056805) (+1) and there is no other intersection up to $n=500000$.

Comment: Wow, well done! I did not find these sequences.

Comment: @Peter So now you know you can continue your search with $n = 500001$.